# Php cake post request

Tags: php, web-services, cakephp, rest

I am developing restful services with PHP Cake. I have developed all get services. But I am stucked in post services.

Problem is that, I am unable to get post data. I am getting noting in $this->data

**Here is code of one controller function.**

```
function signin() {

    $this->view = 'Webservice.Webservice';
    $message = "Request Received";
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $message = "Request has data";
    }


     $this->set(compact('message'));
}
```

**Here is my request data**

```
POST http://localhost/blog/posts/signin HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 25

username=abc&password=abc
```

Please help me out here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake only populates the request data array by data sent to PHP that is prefixed with 'data'.

POST your username and password like this, instead:

```
data[username]=abc&data[password]=abc
```

This will tell Cake to place it in `$this->request->data`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But this is not working as well.

Comment: Are you using the Security component? Is it being blackholed? Have you inspected the request/response via firebug? If you're on 2.x, have you made sure to use `$this->request->data`?

Comment: I am not using Security component. I am using 1.3 version. Yes, I inspected request/response with firebug

Comment: Have you tried turning off checkAgent in config/core.php? Find `Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);` and set it to false.

Comment: No luck with that also. I am getting data with      $message = file_get_contents('php://input');  but not with this->data

Comment: How are you POSTing it (can you add that to the question)? Is `$_POST` populated? `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`? Sounds like it might be a PHP config issue.

Comment: Thanks you very much. My problem has been resolved. I set Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. That change solved my problem. Now I am getting data properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10506/discussion-between-adil-fazal-and-jeremyharris)